# Does monotonicity of a function imply invertibility? What about vice verse?

Tags: functions

A monotone function never has saddle points, same is true for an invertible function. Can we conclude that monotonic function is also invertible and vice-versa?

Comment: It might be a good idea to add a couple of details to your question: From context (including MPW's answer) it seem you're asking about _real-valued functions of one real variable_. Are you also assuming _the domain is an interval_? If not, then no, invertibility does not imply monotonicity.

Comment: @user86418 domain being an interval is not enough unless you also assume continuity

Comment: yes, domain is interval and function is continuous. Would it then be vice-versa?

Comment: use the intermediate value theorem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your statement

> A monotone function never has saddle points

is false. The function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ with $f(x)=x^3$ is (strictly) monotone, has a saddle point at $x=0$, and is invertible with inverse $f^{-1}(y)= y^{1/3}$.

Still, a strictly monotone function $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is invertible with its inverse defined everywhere on $g(\mathbb R)$.

Strict monotonicity is required for invertibility. Nondecreasing step functions show why.

Comment: $f$ is invertible when restricted to any subset of its domain. The point is that is it is false to say that monotone functions cannot have saddle points. They can.

Comment: so monotonicity implies invertibililty and vice-versa?

Comment: the vice-versa is not true and not addresses in the above answer

Comment: @kaka Invertible + continuous implies monotone

Comment: @5xum you also need to assume that the domain is connected

Comment: @Mirko Yes, I was implicitly speaking about functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Note that a monotone function $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ needn't be increasing or decreasing. Continuity is required to force that. Monotonicity of $f:X\to Y$ just means that $f^{-1}(y)$  is connected for each point $y\in Y$.

Comment: Note also that *monotone* and *monotonically increasing* (or *monotonically decreasing*) don't mean the same thing. That's a technical distinction, and I realize that sometimes people say "monotone" when they mean "monotonically increasing". Perhaps that's what OP really meant.